# jQuery Validation plugin: validate check box

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation plugin to validate check box since it does not have default option, One should be selected and max two check boxes can be selected, these is the criteria. I am not getting any error and it is not validating. I am extending it like below,

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" />x
   <input type="checkbox" name="test[]"  />y
   <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" />z
     $("#formid").validate({
  rules: {
    test[]: { 

            required: function(elem)
            {
                return $("input.select:checked").length > 0;
            }

          },
messages: { 

    test[]: "You must check at least 1 box"
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You had several issues with your code.

**1)**  Missing a closing brace, `}`, within your `rules`.

**2)**  In this case, there is no reason to use a function for the `required` rule.  By default, the plugin can handle `checkbox` and `radio` inputs just fine, so using `true` is enough.  However, this will simply do the same logic as in your original function and verify that at least one is checked.

**3)**  If you also want only a maximum of two to be checked, then you'll need to apply the `maxlength` rule.

**4)**  The `messages` option was missing the rule specification.  It will work, but the one custom message would apply to all rules on the same field.

**5)**  If a `name` attribute contains brackets, [you must enclose it within quotes](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29).

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/K6Wvk/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#formid').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            'test[]': {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 2
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'test[]': {
                required: "You must check at least 1 box",
                maxlength: "Check no more than {0} boxes"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can validate group checkbox and radio button without extra js code, see below example.
Your JS should be look like:

```
$("#formid").validate();
```

You can play with HTML tag and attributes: eg. group checkbox [minlength=2 and maxlength=4]

```
<fieldset class="col-md-12">
  <legend>Days</legend>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 form-group">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="daysgroup[]" value="1" required="required" data-msg-required="This value is required." minlength="2" maxlength="4" data-msg-maxlength="Max should be 4">Monday
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="daysgroup[]" value="2">Tuesday
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="daysgroup[]" value="3">Wednesday
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="daysgroup[]" value="4">Thursday
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="daysgroup[]" value="5">Friday
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="daysgroup[]" value="6">Saturday
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="daysgroup[]" value="7">Sunday
        </label>
        <label for="daysgroup[]" class="error">Your error message will be display here.</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

> You can see here first or any one input should have required, minlength="2" and maxlength="4" attributes. minlength/maxlength as per your requirement.

eg. group radio button:

```
<fieldset class="col-md-12">
  <legend>Gender</legend>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12 form-group">
        <label class="form-check-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="gendergroup[]" value="m" required="required" data-msg-required="This value is required.">man
        </label>
        <label class="form-check-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="gendergroup[]" value="w">woman
        </label>
        <label class="form-check-inline">
          <input type="radio" name="gendergroup[]" value="o">other
        </label>
        <label for="gendergroup[]" class="error">Your error message will be display here.</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

You can check working example [here](https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html).

- jQuery v3.3.x
- jQuery Validation Plugin - v1.17.0

Answer (score 0):

Work for me:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group mb-3">
        <label>Vendor Type<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vendorType" value="TABLE" id='table'>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="table"> Table </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox checkbox-success checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vendorType" value="MENU" id='menu'>
            <label class="checkbox-inline" for="menu"> Menu </label>
        </div>
        <div class="text-danger vendorType"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The validation code:

```
vendorType: {
    required: true,
    maxlength: 2
},
```

Error message:

```
vendorType: {
    required: "You must check at least 1 box",
    maxlength: "Check no more than {0} boxes"
},
```

No need to do this `venderType[]` just do `vendorType`

Answer (score -1):

There is the easy way

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" />x
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]"  />y
<input type="checkbox" name="test[]" />z
<button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("#submit").on("click",function(){
    if (($("input[name*='test']:checked").length)<=0) {
        alert("You must check at least 1 box");
    }
    return true;
});
```

For this you not need any plugin.
Enjoy;)

Comment: Maybe it's shorter, but @ram uses validation plugin and that plugin uses the rules in order to validate

Comment: That's true but I put this like solution without additional libraries.

Comment: Yes. jQuery is only library for this solution. You don't need additional plugins or libraryes.