# JQuery form validation conflict

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am using the Jquery form validation library:

jquery-validate.js

When the user submits the form I slide down a div which has a check box which has to be chekced in order to proceed:

```
if(!$('#agreeConfirm').is(':checked')){

     alert('Please tick to agree to our terms and conditions');
     $('.termsAgree').slideDown();
     return true;

}
```

This works in so much as the form is not submitted and the alert displays along with the slideDown which presents the check box. However if one of the select options has not be selected by the user the form submits (although the message 'This field is required' does appear. If I comment out my lines above the correct behavior is observed.

My validation code structure is as follows:

```
$("form#register").validate({

 rules:{

       name:{
           required: true,
           number: false
       },

       .....

       add1:{
       required: true
       }    

 }

});

$('form#register').submit(function(){

     ... 

     if(!$('#agreeConfirm').is(':checked')){

         alert('Please tick to agree to our terms and conditions');
         $('.termsAgree').slideDown();
         return false;

     }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be best to also include the relevant HTML to make this a complete and concise example.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rule for the checkbox in the form validate method for the field. Look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453036/jquery-validation-plugin-validate-check-box).

Comment: thanks but I don't think taht helps in my case, I want to slideDown a div when the validation fails... I don't think I can do that within the validate method

Comment: In `errorPlacement: function(error, element) {}` method you can identify the element if it is checkbox element then you can scroll the DIV. This will solve your problem for sure!

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a whole separate `submit` handler function when using the jQuery Validate plugin.  It's redundant and the cause of your conflict.  The plugin is already automatically "handling" the `submit` event...

The plugin has a `submitHandler` callback function that you would use for anything that needs to be done when a valid form is submitted.

Something more like this...

```
$("form#register").validate({
     rules:{
        name:{
            required: true,
            number: false
        },

       .....

        add1:{
            required: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // something to do when the form is valid
        if(!$('#agreeConfirm').is(':checked')){
            alert('Please tick to agree to our terms and conditions');
            $('.termsAgree').slideDown();
            form.submit();
        };
        return false;
    },
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        // something to do when validation fails
    }
});
```

See all callback options:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate