# Validating individual checkboxes with jQuery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Looking at posts such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/15453130/1032531, I see how I can validate the quantity of checked boxes.

Instead, I wish to validate checkboxes based on some other criteria such as whether another input is filled out.

EDIT.  Context:  Inputs are users home, work, and mobile phone.  Checkboxes are "call me at home", "call me at work", and "call my mobile phone".  They are checkboxes and not radioboxes, and as such, the user will get multiple responses if they check multiple checkboxes.

I've put together the following, however, it appears that jQuery Validator only looks at the first element of a given name.  I can probably change the names to be unique instead of using the `[]`, however, I wish the elements to be posted to the server as an array.

How can this be accomplished?

http://jsfiddle.net/suu44yng/

```
<p>one:
  <input id="one" type="text" value="foo" />
</p>
<p>two:
  <input id="two" type="text" />
</p>
<p>three:
  <input id="three" type="text" value="bar" />
</p>
<hr>

<form id="myform">
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="1" checked data-check="one" />One</p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="2" checked data-check="two" />Two</p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="3" checked data-check="three" />Three</p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" />
  </p>
</form>

(function() {
  $.validator.addMethod("checkboxes", function(value, element, params) {
      console.log(this, value, element, params);
      console.log($(element).data('check'), $('#' + $(element).data('check')).val());
      console.log(!$('#one').val(),!$('#two').val(),!$('#three').val());
      var error = false;
      if (value == 1 && !$('#one').val()) {
        error = true;
      }
      else if (value == 2 && !$('#two').val()) {
        error = true;
      }
      else if (value == 3 && !$('#three').val()) {
        error = true;
      }
      console.log(error)
      if (error) {
        $(element).data('error', value);
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    },
    function(params, element) {
      return $.validator.format('This checkbox is not allowed since ' + $(element).data('error') + ' is empty.')
    })
})();

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
      'test[]': {
        checkboxes: true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert('valid form submitted');
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I can probably change the names to be unique instead"*

That's exactly what you're going to have to do.  This plugin uses the `name` attribute to keep track of input elements and if you have multiple input elements with the same `name`, only the first one will be considered for validation and the others are ignored.

However, when you have a grouping of checkbox or radio elements sharing the same `name`, they are considered as a single data point for the form.  Example: when setting the grouping to `required`, then at least one will need to be checked.

There is no workaround if you want each one to be considered individually with a custom rule.  Naming would have to be specified as `test[1]`, `test[2]`, etc.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test[1]" value="1" checked data-check="one" />One
<input type="checkbox" name="test[2]" value="2" checked data-check="two" />Two
<input type="checkbox" name="test[3]" value="3" checked data-check="three" />Three
```

`rules` object:

```
rules: {
    'test[1]': {
        checkboxes: true
    },
    'test[2]': {
        checkboxes: true
    },
    'test[3]': {
        checkboxes: true
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks Sparky,  I was actually thinking of the same and using names such as `test[n]`, however, I planned on starting at zero and not one.  Haven't really thought through the implications, however.  Another thought was withing the plugin, use the first element to get the name, then use JavaScript to get all elements of that given name, and go from there.  My concern, however, is keeping the message from always being displayed by the first element of the given name.

Comment: @user1032531, I have no idea what you're asking.  All I can tell you is how the plugin was designed to function and that there is no workaround for the unique `name` requirement.