# JQuery Validation on 2D arrays of elements in a form

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validator on a dynamic form. Form Structure is like this.
First, there is an array of checkbox

```
checkbox[1]
checkbox[2]
```

Then inside that checkbox, there are other forms values like this

```
checkbox[1]
        name[1]
        multiple Checkbox[1][]
checkbox[2]
        name[2]
        multiple Checkbox[2][]
```

Now I want to validate if the first checkbox is checked then only validate the first group of fields only.

```
checkbox[1] (Checked)
        name[1]
        multiple Checkbox[1][]
```

Consider multiple Checkbox too.

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score -1):

Simply use [jqueryvalidation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) form and validate all the inputs using jquery code on all inputs textbox and [checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453036/jquery-validation-plugin-validate-check-box). This will initially register validation on all form inputs.

Now, add jquery on parent checkbox change event and toggle disabled attribute on nested elements. jQueryvalidation doesnot validate on disabled inputs.